# 2nd order ODE using Runge-Kutta method in C

Tags: c, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I want to model the motion of a particle using a set of 2nd order equations
the the equation is

```
d2x/dt2 = 1 + dy/dt + dz/dt 
d2y/dt2 = 1 + dx/dt + dz/dt 
d2z/dt2 = 1 + dx/dt + dy/dt
```

vector `V` is `(dx/dt dy/dt dz/dt)`,  `X` is `(x y z)`,
`V = [0 0 0]`, `X = [0 0 0]` initially

I implemented this into C code for one of the ODEs below
CODE;

```
double X_function(double a[], double t, double at[],double b[],double c[]) {
//double yt, zt;
at[0] = a[0];
at[1] = 1 + b[0] + c[0];
double F = at[1];
return F;
}
```

i need help understanding how to use R-K in such a case

Comment: We are not a coding service. This looks like a mathematical problem anyway, not a programming problem. So, how is this specific to the C programming language?

Comment: The code has to be written in C and I just need help in understanding how R-K metod works for second order ODEs

Comment: As I wrote: That's a pure math problem, not programming. What have you done to find out yourself? How about a good math book?

Comment: Perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Runge-Kutta) is the place to go, and/or some googling.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You have an equation

```
x''=F(x,x')
```

that you rewrite as an first order system

```
x' = v
v' = F(x,v)
```

Implement this coupled 6-dimensional system as one function

```
void derivs(double u[], double t, double du[]) {
    int j,k;
    for(k=0; k<3; k++) {
        du[k] = u[3+k];
        du[3+k] = 1;
        for(j=0;j<3; j++) 
            if(j!=k) du[3+k] += u[j]
    }
}
```

then you can implement the Runge-Kutta method in a general form for a first-order system.

Comment: Just to understand it better how can i get an output from this function?

Comment: The output is in `du`. As you pass only the pointer, the array you pass in the call to the `derivs` function will still contain the new values after the call.